# How do I configure the preferences of a project in codelite?

Tags: settings, project, codelite

I have codelite 5.2, windows 10, C language, how can I configure the preferences of a project so that it finds the libraries (.h) of another project (of the library, static library) in the same workspace?

[image]

I have tried to put various paths but I always get: mylibrary.h: no such file or directory
Please, I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:
Your CodeLite version is wrong, I think that it is `14.0.4` (CodeLite Makefile Generator was added in this release)

In order to tell the compiler (not CodeLite) where to search for header filee:

- In the project settings dialog (the one in the picture) select the `Compiler` tab from the tree view on the right
- Select the `Include paths` and there the location where the header files (`*.h`) can be found

Note that adding the header files is usually not enough, because you will also need to link against these libraries.
To do this:

- In the project settings dialog, select the `Linker` tab
- In the linker page, update the location of the library files (`.a` or `.dll`) in the `Libraries search path` and you will also need to pass the library name in the `Libraries` field

HTH,
Eran